# Parse xml to pdf according to a template in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, thymeleaf, freemarker

I need to parse an xml to pdf according to a template that doesn't requiere to generate again a war and redeploy in my server.

I use JAXB to parse xml to my java entities, after that I want to generate a pdf according to a template configurable in some kind of file that doesn't requiere to rebuild my code and redeploy it in my server, so I can change my template configuration to convert the xml to pdf.

In other words, I have my full aplication that parses xml, I want to export my information to pdf according to a template file, this should be reconfigurable so I have not to redeploy my app, it must be only a properties file

Comment: How would you convert xml data to a pdf file? How does a war file and a server come into the picture all of a sudden? Please enhance the question, nobody can help you like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, the functionality you want to implemente is:

1. A xml to pdf framework
2. A server program, which implements an interface for external calls

2.1. Then input param of the interface is:

2.1.1. Config file in xml format(let's call it param1)

2.1.2. Business data(let's call it param2)

2.2. The output result of the interface is:

2.2.2. pdf format files

The internal logic of the server program is: call the xml to pdf framework, send param1 and param2 parameter.

Therefore, the main difficulty lies in 1: a xml to pdf framework

And nanhu-print-java happens to be an xml to pdf framework.

An hello world demo of xml to pdf is:

1. Configure file of xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns="https://github.com/hongjinqiu/nanhu-print-java" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <style></style>
    <macros></macros>
    <body pageSizePdf="A4" rotate="false" paddingLeft="50px" paddingRight="50px" paddingTop="30px" paddingBottom="20px" width="685px" height="840px">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" tableLayout="fixed" explain="true">
            <tbody><tr><td>
                        <span value="hello world," />
                        <span value="js:businessData" />
            </td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Business data is:

```
{
  "businessData": "I am businessData"
}
```

3. How to use the framework:

Add maven dependencies of nanhu-print-java framework:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hongjinqiu</groupId>
    <artifactId>nanhu-print-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The code:

```
package com.hongjinqiu.demo;

import com.hongjinqiu.nanhuprint.NanhuprintInterpreter;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NanhuprintInterpreter nanhuprintInterpreter = new NanhuprintInterpreter();
        String filePath = "/tmp/hello_world.pdf";
        try (InputStream in = HelloWorld.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hello_world.json");
             InputStream xmlIn = HelloWorld.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hello_world.xml")
        ) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream xmlOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copyLarge(xmlIn, xmlOut);
            String metaString = xmlOut.toString("utf8");

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copyLarge(in, out);
            String envJson = out.toString("utf8");

            Map<String, Object> env = JSONObject.fromObject(envJson);
            nanhuprintInterpreter.interpreterString(filePath, metaString, env);
        }
    }
}
```

The result page of pdf is:
[hello world result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyJ7Y.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why was so hard for you to understand, I think it's not Klingon. I finally solved it thanks to Thymeleaf, I deployed my app in my server and with thymeleaf templates I can configure the output dinamically without redeploying